# Property name expected type of string but got null of apollo-codegen Error

Tags: reactjs, apollo, codegen

everyone!

I hope your help...!

I created a React project with CRA,

The backend is graphql + node on port 3000.

It works fine "http://localhost:5000"

Also the script 'precodegen' works fine, so, generated schema.json in client.

However, the following error occurs in the codegen command.

Help me please...! Thank you~!

### package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "precodegen": "apollo-codegen introspect-schema http://localhost:5000/graphql --output schema.json",
    "codegen": "apollo-codegen generate './src/**/!(*.local).ts'  --addTypename  --schema schema.json --target typescript --output ./src/__generated__/api.d.ts"
  },
```

### TERMINAL ERROR

```sh
yarn codegen
yarn run v1.17.3
$ apollo-codegen introspect-schema http://localhost:5000/graphql --output schema.json
$ apollo-codegen generate './src/**/!(*.local).ts'  --addTypename  --schema schema.json --target typescript --output ./src/__generated__/api.d.ts
TypeError: Property name expected type of string but got null
    at validate (/Users/jongseoklee/dev/ts-graphql/client/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/utils.js:159:13)
    at Object.validate (/Users/jongseoklee/dev/ts-graphql/client/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/utils.js:196:7)
    at validateField (/Users/jongseoklee/dev/ts-graphql/client/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/validate.js:24:9)
    at validate (/Users/jongseoklee/dev/ts-graphql/client/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/validate.js:17:3)
    at builder (/Users/jongseoklee/dev/ts-graphql/client/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/builder.js:38:27)
    at Object.Identifier (/Users/jongseoklee/dev/ts-graphql/client/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/builders/generated/index.js:334:31)
    at nonNullableTypeFromGraphQLType (/Users/jongseoklee/dev/ts-graphql/client/node_modules/apollo-codegen-typescript/src/helpers.ts:47:34)
    at TypescriptAPIGenerator.typeFromGraphQLType (/Users/jongseoklee/dev/ts-graphql/client/node_modules/apollo-codegen-typescript/src/helpers.ts:55:20)
    at TypescriptAPIGenerator.handleFieldValue (/Users/jongseoklee/dev/ts-graphql/client/node_modules/apollo-codegen-typescript/src/codeGeneration.ts:428:20)
    at /Users/jongseoklee/dev/ts-graphql/client/node_modules/apollo-codegen-typescript/src/codeGeneration.ts:347:20
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to install apollo-codegen using yarn in my project only and was getting this error. When I followed the instructions to install apollo-codegen globally, this error went away. Not the solution that I want but it seems fine for now.